# Google Sheets add HTML tags to numbers within the cell

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I'm working on populating a website with over a 100 pages using a CSV file.

Cells have a mix of numbers and letters. I'm looking for a way to find all numbers in a cell and add HTML tags in them.

No only is it numbers but also +, -, % and .

Any suggestions?

[image: Image here]

Comment: Are you wanting to populate a new cell or actually modify the contents of the original cell?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: @Fering Added the image in the question. :)

Comment: @player0 Image posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(QUERY(FLATTEN(IF(ISNUMBER(SPLIT(A1, " "))+
 (REGEXMATCH(""&SPLIT(A1, " "), "%")), "<span class=""numbers"">"&
 SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(A1, "%", "%♥"), " ")&"</span>", SPLIT(A1, " ")))
 ,,999^99), "♥", ))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Omg it works! One last q. If for example I have "23s" as well and would like to encapsulate it with the HTML tags?

Comment: Sorry. Tried applying it. Seems it is capturing most if not all. :( 

@player0 Whatyou think is the prob? Seems the next line or end of the line is not handled well :( 

[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GqMd2jL6jdYq4WbRMDnVA4LpCp0pWGKx/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @GamingalaPip try like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbT3L.png

Comment: Created a sample page to test on the data here [link] (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Cd86s3n3q3kyPO3C6v4nFnOg3qj1SwulXhBNbg1baYM/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: I think it's the Char(10) that's messingit up. Notice the sample data in the doc.

Comment: indeed. fixed https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AQw6.png see your sample sheet

Comment: You rock. I saw the modifications. Have to learn Regexmatch. It seems to be supper powerful. My first prototype was all SUBSTITUTE can you image how the output would have looked like. 

Total life saver. Thanks so much!